# $http.get cache false is not working

Tags: angularjs

i am using this code to call the method but it is still keeping the cache and not refreshing the data on the screen

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    app.controller('categoryController', ['$http', '$location', 'authService', 'ngWEBAPISettings', categoryController]);

    ////categoryController.$inject = ['$location']; 

    function categoryController($http, $location, authService, ngWEBAPISettings) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */

        //Creating headers for sending the authentication token along with the system.
        var authheaders = {};
        authheaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authService.getToken();

        //ForDate
        var d = new Date();

        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Category';
        ////debugger;

        ////Vadiable for Grid
        vm.Category = [];

        ////Vadiable for Adding
        vm.category = {
            CategoryID: 0,
            CategoryName:"",
            CreatedOn:d,
            UpdatedOn:d
        };
    ////Vadiable for Editing
    vm.editCategory = {};

    vm.getCategory = function () {
        ////debugger;

        ////authheaders.cache = false;


        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authheaders.Authorization
            },
            cache: false,
        };


        //For Grid
        $http.get(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", config)
        .then(function (respose) {
            //success
            ////debugger;
            angular.copy(respose.data, vm.Category);
            ////debugger;
            //var i = 2;
            ////debugger;
        }, function (response) {
            //failure
            ////debugger;
        }).finally(function () {
            ////debugger;
            //finally
        }
        );
    }

    vm.add = function ()
    {
        ////authheaders.Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        ////debugger;

        vm.category.CreatedOn = d;
        vm.category.UpdatedOn = d;

        $http.post(ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/Categories", JSON.stringify(vm.category), { headers: authheaders })
        .then(function (repose) {
            ////success
            ////debugger;
            vm.Category.push(repose.data);
            alert('Category has been addded successfully');
            $('#addModal').modal('hide');
        }, function (response) {
            ////failure
            ////debugger;
            alert('An error has been occurred while adding the data');
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.category = {};
        });
    }

    vm.edit = function (id) {
        ///debugger;
        ////alert(id);
        $('#btnSubmit').html('Update');

        $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("ng-click");
        $("#btnSubmit").attr("ng-click", "vm.edit()");

        $('#addModal').modal('show');

    }
    vm.delete = function (id) {
        ////debugger;
        alert(id);
    }


    activate();
    function activate() { vm.getCategory(); }

}
})();
```

here is the html

```
            <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>

           <div id="addModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Add Category</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Category Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control col-md-9" type="text" name="txtcategoryname" id="txtcategoryname" maxlength="200" ng-model="vm.category.CategoryName" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!vm.category.CategoryName"  ng-click="vm.add()">Add</button>
            </div>
               </div>
              </div>
       </div>
              <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-10">
        <a href="" onclick="openAddModal()"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-200px"></span> Add New Record</a>

    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cat in vm.Category">
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.categoryName}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">{{cat.createdOn | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.edit(cat.categoryID)" value="Edit" />
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.delete(cat.categoryID)" value="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openAddModal() {
        $('#addModal').modal('show');
        $('#btnSubmit').val('Add');
    }
</script>
```

here it is get called from

```
function activate() { vm.getCategory(); }
```

Comment: please have a look on html

Comment: getCategory() is never called anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: please have a look now

Comment: Were you able to get the debugger at the server side ? Did you mean its caching at client side or server side ? Please try not using Angular.copy once to see if this fixes

Comment: it is caching it at client side

Comment: Again, it's very unclear. activate() is called a single time from the controller. So how do you know that it uses or doesn't use the cache? And which cache are you talking about? The angular cache, or the browser cache? When you look at the network panel in the browser dev tools, do you see a request each time you click on the button triggering this $http call (assuming there is one somewhere), or not?

Comment: Try removing the hanging comma after the cache statement.                                var config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authheaders.Authorization
            },
            cache: false,
        };

Comment: this link in stack overflow works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098430/angular-ie-caching-issue-for-http

Comment: So your problem is resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works for me

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    //initialize get if not there
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }

    //disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    // extra
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does disable cache for all get requests.

```
myApp.config([
            // Diable IE Cache for $http.get requests
            '$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
                // Initialize get if not there
                if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
                    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
                }
                // Enables Request.IsAjaxRequest() in ASP.NET MVC
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

                // Disable IE ajax request caching
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
            }
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this Angular link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http caching is disabled by default. Check if you have a global setting somewhere for the cache and disable if needed.

Also try this solution by adding a datetime parameter in querystring.
[Destroying AngularJS $Http.Get Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34075762/destroying-angularjs-http-get-cache?rq=1)

Comment: but for the get it is enabled as mentioned                                                           Only GET and JSONP requests are cached.